# Access Denied when trying to access a website using selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to access a website using selenium, but I got denied. I am running on windows computer.

The message I got when trying to access the website:

**Access Denied**
You don't have permission to access "http://www.blibli.com/login?" on this server.
Reference #18.86fa3b17.1634227013.1a33b6

Is there anything I can do to access it using selenium?

Thank you.

Below is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

CHROME_DRIVER_PATH = "C:\Development\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
URL = "https://www.blibli.com/member/order/retail/ongoing"
EMAIL = "rickycandra453@gmail.com"
BLIBLI_PASSWORD = BLIBLI_PASSWORD




class Blibli:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER_PATH)

    def login(self):
        self.driver.get(URL)

    def get_data(self):
        pass

bot = Blibli()
bot.login()
bot.get_data()
```

Answer (score 0):

To log in you need to submit the credential to the login screen.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

self.driver.get('login_url_here')
elem = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="username"]')
elem.send_keys('user)
elem = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="password"]')
elem.send_keys('password', Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: O yeah, thabks for reminding, I will try it and let you know ok